# CoreML performance cost of Vision Framework vs. CVPixelBuffer?

Tags: ios, coreml, apple-vision

There are two options for passing images into CoreML models:

1. Pass in a [CGImage](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreml/mlfeaturevalue/3200161-init) to Vision Framework with its [niceties](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60125910/8766790)
2. Pass in a CVPixelBuffer [directly](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreml/mlfeaturevalue/2879346-init)

**Is there any data on the memory and processing overhead associated with using the Vision framework vs. passing a CVPixelBuffer directly to CoreML?**

Thoughts based on what I've seen while debugging:

##### Memory

Assuming we already have the data in a CVPixelBuffer, creating the CGImage to pass to Vision seems to double the memory usage.  It looks like Vision is creating a new object in CoreVideo/CoreImage from `createPixelBufferFromVNImageBuffer` which makes sense as it needs to create a copy of the image to crop/rotate/scale.

##### Processing

You're going to have to do the rotation and/or scaling either way.  I'd assume Vision does those at least as efficiently as you could do by hand with Accelerate.  So should not be any overhead here.

Comment: Use `CVPixelBuffer` if you already have it, preferably in BGRA pixel order (or YUV) as opposed to ARGB.

Comment: The person who wrote the book! I think I might see if I can do the rotation and scaling with Accelerate without too much of a perf or maintainability hit.

Comment: Vision can automatically do cropping and rotation (in steps of 90 degrees).